# How to cite editorial article?

Tags: citations

If admins allow me I would like to put a link, https://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v11/n9/full/nnano.2016.180.html 
as a example, I dont know how to cite it since this is not really paper and it is not signed by any author.
Also I took a lot of from it. Can I say: According to NN editorial?and than put quotation mark? is it same as citing a book?

Comment: I think your question is basically "How do I cite a work with no author?".

Comment: authors are editors? @Sverre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify the citation style, I chose APA at [citethisforme.com](http://www.citethisforme.com), selected *journal article* and entered the DOI. This is the result:

In-text: ("A matter of scale", 2016)

Bibliography: A matter of scale. (2016). Nature Nanotechnology, 11(9), 733-733. http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nnano.2016.180

Even so it is an Editorial and has no author, it is still sort of a journal article since it is published in a journal with volume and issue and has a DOI. Therefore, I'd suggest this solution.

Comment: There are thousands of citation styles. Do you know all of them? I don't. But in general: If you cannot identify an author **as in your case**, how should you name one? **If** there was an author, the author would occur at least in the bibliography in most citation styles. But this doesn't apply to your initial question.